# Updating a running bash file

Tags: windows, bash, git, git-bash

I have the following function in a bash script. Let's call this script `example.sh`. It's inside a git repository that should update.

**example.sh** (simplified version)

```
# Directory of script
dir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"

update() {
  ( cd "$dir" && git pull )
}

if [ "$1" == "update" ]; then
  update
fi
```

Then I call `example.sh update` (which calls the function) so it executes the `git pull`.

Now the issue is when there's a change in `example.sh`, it needs to update itself. Linux has no problem doing that, but GitBash (Windows..) complains saying:

> error: unable to create file example.sh: Permission denied

probably because it's in use for still running `example.sh update` and waiting for `git pull` to finish.

I already tried

```
( cd "$dir" && git pull & )
```

and

```
bash -c "sleep 1 && cd \"$dir\" && git pull" &
```

How can I fire a new process to update this repo so that no files are in use at the moment of `git pull`ing?

Comment: probably nothing can be done. For some reason bash and also some other shells I have tried keep a descriptor to the script file while running.

Comment: Did you ever try my solution? I'm curious myself whether it worked or not.

Answer (score 0):

For the lack of GitBash for Windows I wasn't able to test the following suggestion. I would be happy if you could give me some feedback.

At the beginning of your script, add

```
#! /bin/bash

self="$(sed '0,/^# ACTUALSCRIPT/d' "$BASH_SOURCE")"
exec bash -c "$self" "$0" "$@"
# ACTUALSCRIPT (keep this comment, the script relies on it)

# your old script
# ...
```

This will replace the script's process with a new `bash` process which reads commands from its arguments and not from a file.

Please note that your detection of the script's directory probably won't work inside `bash -c`. You can pass the directory as an argument if needed. Alternatively, you can `cd` *before* `exec` such that the new process starts in the correct directory.