# Is there a way to bundle the bash interpreter along with the script?

Tags: bash, shell, bundle, interpreter

I would like to avoid bugs/behaviors from the old versions of the bash interpreter, is there a solution to bundle a recent(like, >4.3) bash interpreter along with the script?

Comment: it may be easier if you use other languages like python which is much more stable than bash.

Comment: I think there could be a way similar to the approaches in the answers [combine script and zip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49351570/6770384) and [overwrite running script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55730023/6770384). However, you probably have to compile bash statically linked. Also, the tools you call from inside your script (for instance `grep`, `sed`, ...) are still dependent on the user's platform even with a bundled bash.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad idea to write a script used for in a specific version of a shell. Write POSIX compliant shell scripts, it is not that difficult.

However, you can declare what interpreter is needed for the script at the top of your file with a shebang:

`#!/path/to/interpreter`

A common (and recommended) shebang for shell scripts is:

`#!/bin/sh` which links to the system shell.

If you want a particular shell, like bash, you would write:
`#!/bin/bash`

For requiring specific versions of bash, you would need to write a check to verify the version of bash that is present.

Comment: "not that difficult" depends on what the OP is trying to acheive.  For some things, POSIX sh is fine, for others it is sorely lacking in basic programming language features and that can make life quite difficult.  For example POSIX doesn't support arrays.  Depending on context the best approximation is to represent arrays as files with one line per entry, which sucks.